# Equivalent resistance problem

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

I'm trying to find the equivalent resistance to this problem.

The 6 ohm and 3 ohm resistor are in parallel since they connect at both ends. What would be the next step?

Comment: Redraw it dude so it doesn't look as confusing. 10R and 15R in parallel across the 15 volt supply. 6R||3R in series with 28R are also across the supply. I get 5 ohm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like a homework question so I won't give the final answer. If you redraw the circuit it becomes obvious what you need to do,

[image]